# How to define arbitrary tasks in the Play Framework? (like ruby rake)

Tags: playframework, rake

How to define arbitrary tasks in the Play Framework?

I mean tasks run from the command line, something similar to ruby rake.

I'm aware of the ant tool but looking for a better alternative.

Comment: What kind of tasks you want to run ? If you need it for building purposes play is quite good about it. You dont have to need any other tool. But if you need for scheduling some tasks like mail sending , reindexing vs.. you can use Job class in Play.

Comment: All kinds of non-standard tasks: generating asciidoc documentation, database initialization and migrations, non-standard automated tests, etc.

Comment: "tasks" is a bit ambiguous, though in rake that's how they are called. In Play! they are "commands"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[edit]** *This answer is for the Play 1.* series!*

You should write a custom module, then your commands go into the `commands.py` file, ref: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/releasenotes-1.1#commands

You can look at existing modules to get inspired, eg: https://github.com/sim51/logisima-play-yml/blob/master/commands.py

Basically you define the commands you want and launch them from the "execute" method, eg:

```
COMMANDS = ['namespace:command']

def execute(**kargs):
    command = kargs.get("command")
    app = kargs.get("app")
    args = kargs.get("args")
    env = kargs.get("env")

    if command == "namespace:command":
        do_something()
```

if you want to launch something java - often the case! -:

```
def do_something():
    java_cmd = app.java_cmd([], None, "play.modules.mymodule.MyClass", args)
        try:
            subprocess.call(java_cmd, env=os.environ)
        except OSError:
            print "Could not execute the java executable, please make sure the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set properly (the java executable should reside at JAVA_HOME/bin/java). "
            sys.exit(-1)
        print
```

Ps.

creating a custom module is as easy as:

```
play new-module mymodule
```

This is a primer: http://playframework.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/play-modules/ , considering that official [Play! module documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/modules) is quite limited in that respect

**edit**

I thought I'd add a little piece of information:

before being able to execute your commands, you must BUILD your module. It does not run like the rest of play with a dynamic compilation.

```
play build-module mymodule
```

new-module/build-module expect the module to be at the root of the project folder, but if you have many that becomes a mess. `build-module module-srcs/mymodule` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks Stefano. This really looks like "The Play 1.2.4 Way" to define custom tasks.

Unfortunately, AFAIK Python is going to be abandoned in Play 2.0. 

Will I have to rewrite my commands in Scala then?

Comment: @qertoip unluckily Play! 2.0 is still in very early stage - but as said [in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044991/how-to-contribute-modules-in-play-framework-2-0) modules should be actually easier to write. If write your command mostly as java you should be able to reuse it entirely once 2.0 is out for production - which is not gonna happen soon, and probably you'll have a lot of additional work to adapt your whole application, more than to rewrite your command :)

Comment: @qertoip oh, I did not notice the "in Scala" in your comment, sorry! Don't worry, Play! 2.0 is NOT abadoning Java! `Java, on the other hand, is certainly not getting any less support 
from Play 2.0; quite the contrary. The Play 2.0 build provides us with 
an opportunity to enhance the development experience for Java 
developers.` from this [official announcement](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/8cdca8216bffc464)

Answer (score 7):

For Play 2, you can create new tasks using SBT, by following the documentation here:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks

In the context of a Play 2 generated `Build.scala`, it might look like this:

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build { 

  val appName         = "foo"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    jdbc,
    anorm
  )

  val hello = TaskKey[Unit]("hello", "Prints 'Hello World'")

  val helloTask = hello := {
    println("Hello World")
  }

  lazy val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    helloTask
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you James. Based on your advice, I wrote down the sample code that loads application in SBT task on [my blog](http://kailuowang.blogspot.com/2013/05/define-arbitrary-tasks-in-play-21.html)

Comment: would you mind taking a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447100/cant-get-access-to-a-projects-classes-objects-from-build-scala ?