# Can't get access to a project's classes / objects from Build.scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'd like to create the task like Ruby rake. I know I can do by sbt tasks http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks But I can't use any class or object from my project. For example:

```
# project/AppBuild.scala
object AppBuild extends Build {
  //............
    lazy val sampleTask = taskKey[Unit]("hello123", "A sample task.") := {
      val u = models.User.single(123) // Error! models is not accessible
    }

}
```

So I can't get access to models.User or any other class in my project. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala is strongly typed, all types must be resolved at compile time.  Your build file is first compiled - it can't depend on types from the project it's building since to build the project it is building it first needs to be built itself - see the circular dependency?

So you can't simply call Scala code in your project from your build file.

What you can do is define a main class in your project, and tell SBT to invoke that using the `runMain` task.  This does all the magic necessary to first compile your project, then create a classloader with all the necessary dependencies, then lookup your main class reflectively and invoke it.  Note that presumably your code needs a running application, so you'll be best off to do this in the `test` folder and use Play's fake application helper, eg:

```
package foo.bar

import play.api.test._
object MyMainClass extends App {
  Helpers.running(FakeApplication()) {
    val u = models.User.single(123)
    ...
  }
}
```

Now from the `play` console, try this:

```
test:runMain foo.bar.MyMainClass
```

If that works, then you can shorten it by adding this to your `build.sbt` or build settings in `Build.scala`:

```
TaskKey[Unit]("do-something", "Do something") := {
  (runMain in Test).toTask("foo.bar.MyMainClass").value
}
```

Then you should just be able to run `do-something`.

Comment: 'test:runMain foo.bar.MyMainClass' from Play console doesn't look good because it has nothing to do with Test. Actually, look at this http://kailuowang.blogspot.com/2013/05/define-arbitrary-tasks-in-play-21.html - it's done by reflection, very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Build.scala defines how to build the project. In the build definition you are trying to use something that should be built based on that definition.

General answer is that `models` has to be built before (a separate module) and added as a dependency for the build project (not for the "real" project).

But the whole idea that you need something from the project to actually build the project sounds suspicious. Perhaps somebody can come up with a better answer if you explain why and what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: it's not suspicious, I just want to be able to run "sbt insertPredefinedUsers" in database.

Comment: `added as a dependency for the build project (not for the "real" project)` - what's the different between the build project and "real" project?

Comment: 1) I think it is very unusual to insert something to DB related to the project during compilation of that project.

Comment: 2) In SBT the structure is recursive. Let's say you have a project in a root directory. Then in /project subdirectory you have another project which defines how to build "the project" in the root dir. If you wish, you can have a /project/project which defines how to build the project to build the project ...

My idea was to add dependency to the build project inside the /project directory.

Comment: 1) what does it have to do with compilation?

Comment: @Alex You are trying to use a hammer to build the very same hammer. Not just any hammer, but the same one.

Comment: whatever I use it works, I found the solution and I can say "sbt myTask".

Comment: @Alex I'm interested to see that. You can post it here and answer your own question. Thanks

Comment: so what about the hammer?