# How to build a module in playframework 2

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

It seems I can't find an instruction on http://www.playframework.org/ about building a module for playframework 2.

Anyone know if there are documentations for this or the steps require to build a module?

Thanks.

Comment: The sites that you need to bookmark for useful tuts and tips: http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/ and of course http://playframework.wordpress.com/

Comment: I think you r question Is similar to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044991/how-to-contribute-modules-in-play-framework-2-0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This link is by far the best guide I have seen for far.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/writing-modules-play-2-get

The author, Steve, has been working with Play modules for quite some time, and has published a few Play2 modules based on his Play 1.x ones.

Comment: It's in java. can you give me a link for scala??

Answer (score 1):

I too didnt find any good documentation on this. So, I figured it myself and captured the steps in this post. It targets Play 2.5 and above. It is in Java!

https://medium.com/confest/writing-a-play-module-e8cc95cb9285#.y7zt92vpa

Answer (score 0):

There isn't official documentation as of the writing of this answer.  But there are links to documentation off of the playframework website here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/Modules

From the above link:

> Blog posts describing the process of writing a module can be found on http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=363 and http://developer.vz.net/2012/03/16/writing-a-play-2-0-module/

The second link is actually how to build a plug-in, which is just a module that implements a specific interface to provide a way to hook into the framework during startup and shutdown, I believe.

Also the guide in the previous answer seems like it might be good too: http://java.dzone.com/articles/writing-modules-play-2-get